# How to clear the WKBackForwardList of a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

It appears that the `backForwardList` of a WKWebView is readonly, but I've seen people so some pretty magical things to get around this. I need to figure out some way of clearing the history of a WKWebView. Any ideas how I might so this? So far I've tries a few tricks that have failed:

- using keyValue:forKey didn't work.
- using a C pointer `->` didnt work.

I've seen people talk about synthesizing the property and extending the class but I don't really know how that works and couldn't figure it out. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could try implementing your own storage... `WKBackForwardList` IS immutable

Comment: What about using: `allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures`, `canGoBack` or `canGoForward`? Or do you specifically need to clear `backForwardList`?

Comment: @nyg I need to clear the history, not just prevent swipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code compiles, but I have not tested it...

First I subclass `WKWebView` to override `backForwardList` with my own subclass of `WKBackForwardList`.

Then, in my `WKBackForwardList` subclass, I can either override `backItem` & `forwardItem` to make them return nil, instead of having them look into their respective list (which is most probably the default implementation).

Or I can override `backList` & `forwardList` in the same way I did in `WKWebView` with `backForwardList`. I do this to add a setter, which will allow me remove items from the lists.

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

class WebViewHistory: WKBackForwardList {

    /* Solution 1: return nil, discarding what is in backList & forwardList */

    override var backItem: WKBackForwardListItem? {
        return nil
    }

    override var forwardItem: WKBackForwardListItem? {
        return nil
    }

    /* Solution 2: override backList and forwardList to add a setter */

    var myBackList = [WKBackForwardListItem]()

    override var backList: [WKBackForwardListItem] {
        get {
            return myBackList
        }
        set(list) {
            myBackList = list
        }
    }

    func clearBackList() {
        backList.removeAll()
    }
}

class WebView: WKWebView {

    var history: WebViewHistory

    override var backForwardList: WebViewHistory {
        return history
    }

    init(frame: CGRect, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, history: WebViewHistory) {
        self.history = history
        super.init(frame: frame, configuration: configuration)
    }

    /* Not sure about the best way to handle this part, it was just required for the code to compile... */

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {

        if let history = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "history") as? WebViewHistory {
            self.history = history
        }
        else {
            history = WebViewHistory()
        }

        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        super.encode(with: aCoder)
        aCoder.encode(history, forKey: "history")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Trying to figure out how to convert this into Objective C and integrate into this plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/blob/master/src/ios/CDVWKWebViewEngine.m#L62

Comment: Here's my attempt -- doesn't seem to work though. https://github.com/ccorcos/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/commit/ae78c110a283eda9658f44f51125670fe54b1aa9  Again, I'm not an Objective C expert my any means...

Comment: I feel like I'm pretty close though. Currently getting this error: `-[WKWebView clearHistory]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: @Chet I saw your latest commit which fixed a typo in the name of the method. Did that solved the error?

Comment: No, I get a runtime error saying that its not a CVDWKWebView... :/ Never figured it out

Comment: @Chet Check in `CDVWKWebViewEngine.m`, line 138, you're still using `[WKWebView alloc]`. I think it should be `[CVDWKWebView alloc]` no?

Comment: Ah you're right!! I was only looking at line 108. Thanks for the help -- I'll let you know if this works!

Comment: backForwardList never changes during navigation. it remains empty in my app. what's wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, this brilliant idea doesn't work. It seems that `backList` is simply a derived property, and it's therefore not used internally by WebKit to store the actual visited items.

Comment: indeed, doesn't work. A workaround is to create a new WKWebView and pass the old configuration.

Answer (score 6):

Worded on iOS8 ~ iOS11.

Objective-C

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
[wek.backForwardList performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"_removeAllItems")];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Swift 4

```
webView.backForwardList.perform(Selector(("_removeAllItems")))
```

!!!!NOTE!!!! THIS METHOD IS DECLARED IN WebKit Open Resource, not a public method。

Comment: What does "declear" mean, and secondly, where did you find out how to do this?

Comment: @Chet It's "declared".Spell error. Find in WebKit Open Resource

Comment: xu tong's solution will accept by apple ?
Is there any rejection due to this ?

Comment: Definetely gonna be rejected for using this method. It's very simple, it's not listed in the WKBackForwardList api doc, so it's private api. A very bad way to solve the problem and to generate crashes when Apple decides to change that signature in the future version of iOS.

Comment: It means it is working now but it's not a documented method, so you're not supposed to use it because it could go away without warning.

Answer (score 3):

Because Apple keeps the interface for `WKBackForwardList` pretty tightly locked down and is notoriously strict with developers who go outside of the [published public interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414977-backforwardlist), you have two options:

1. The easiest way (and surely what Apple intends) is to create a new `WKWebView` and replace your current one with it. This isn't that hard of a solution to implement since there are a pretty finite number of configurations you could have to copy over from your old instance to your new one. You could even create a wrapper view that did this for you, so that you only ever had to call `clearHistory()` and the wrapper view would do the underlying swap for you.
2. If, for some reason, you can't replace the instance of `WKWebView`, you can take advantage of the 1D nature of history to clear the history **down to two items**. You cannot clear it farther than that, I'm afraid. To clear the URL down to two URLs, let's say they're stored in the values urlA and urlB, you would do:

```swift
// At initialization, ensure that urlA is the first item in the history
let webview = WKWebView()
// ... whatever other init you need
webview.load(URLRequest(url: urlA))
```

and then to "clear" the history:

```swift
func clearHistory() {
    // First we make sure the webview is on the earliest item in the history
    if webview.canGoBack {
        webview.go(to: webview.backForwardList.backList.first)
    }
    // Then we navigate to our urlB so that we destroy the old "forward" stack
    webview.load(URLRequest(url: urlB))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading in the documentation you can get WKBackForwardList for the WKWebView. 
After that you can find the first item in the backList of WKBackForwardList and after that to use: 
`func go(to: WKBackForwardListItem) -> WKNavigation?` 
And with this you can clean the history up to the first url.